# Is the javascript function Window.open streaming or downloading the file?

Tags: javascript, extjs, window.open

I was wondering if ,by using the Javascript function `window.open()` to preview a file stored on a server, this process was using streaming or downloading ?
What i mean is: how can i make sure the user will only be able to SEE the file, but not downloading it ? ( unless he has permission to)

If this is impossible, any suggestions ? :)

PS :I am using Sencha 3.4 ( Ext.js).

Comment: `window.open` opens a new browser window or tab - no more, no less. In regard to your question it has no relevance _at all_ - things would be the same if they were happening just inside the “original” window/tab. And no, what you want is of course impossible - the browser has _already_ downloaded the data, otherwise it could not display it in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

executing `window.open()` only opens an new browser window or tab. So by providing the link to your file in the function the user have full access to the exact location of the file and can download it.

There is also no such thing as "streaming" a file. To be previewed the file will be downloaded and stored in cache.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! and sorry if my question did appear stupid for some people ( i'm just trying to learn .. :c ). Have a good day :)